# How do I reference all files including hidden files?

Tags: bash

I know that * references all files excluding hidden files, how to reference all files including hidden files whose names begin with a `.` in bash?

Comment: (Sidenote warning: all directory entries, including those starting with `.`, would in particular include the "current directory" entry `.` and the "parent directory" entry `..`. Just so you're warned.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz yes, `.*` references all hidden files including "current directory" and "parent directory"

Comment: Outside the bash-specific scope of the question, but zsh's globbing has handy type qualifiers, so that you can use e.g. `ls .*(.)` which will match only regular files `(.)`, not symlinks `(@)` or directories `(/)` or the like. Especially helpful when doing e.g. `grep something **/*(.)`, which will grep inside all regular files at any depth below the current directory, without throwing errors for trying to grep inside the directory entries themselves.

Answer (score 12):

bash has a [`dotglob` option](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_08) that makes `*` include names starting with `.`:

```
echo *           # let's see some files
shopt -s dotglob # enable dotglob
echo *           # now with dotfiles
shopt -u dotglob # disable dotglob again
echo *           # back to the beginning
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the shell option dotglob:

```
shopt  -s dotglob
echo *
```

For more information,  see the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use [brace expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) and write `{,.}*` which expands to `* .*` and thus includes both normal and hidden files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this has a problem. When used in a recursive command, it also affects the previous directory (..) and all subdirectories in the previous directory! This command should only affect files and directories contained in the CURRENT directory (and the ones contained in each recursively read directory), but it should never go up in the hierarchy and affect neightbouring directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
files=($(ls -a))
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  echo "${file}"
done
```

Comment: fails on unusual filenames with spaces or tabs or newlines etc.

Comment: The cleaned-up version of this would be to use `IFS="^v^j"` (actually type Ctrl-v and Ctrl-j) to set the input separator to newline, then `ls -A -1` to list the matches one-per-line. (`ls -A` explicitly _excludes_ `.` and `..` from the `-a` listing, it's good to get in the habit of using because it's almost *always* what you really want.) Of course, none of that would be necessary if `ls` supported null-delimited output lists, then you could just pipe its output to `xargs -0`. Never understood why there's no support for an `ls -0` parameter.

Comment: What are you on windows?